# discord.py AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'

Tags: python, forms, discord.py

I'm currently building a discord bot with Python that will disrupt a form.

When I run my code this error comes: `AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'`

```py
@bot.command()
async def testform(ctx):
    form = Form(ctx,'Title')
    form.add_question('Question 1','first')
    form.add_question('Question 2','second')
    form.add_question('Question 3','third')
    await form.start()
```

Error:

```py
2023-09-09 08:58:09 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command testform
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspaces/moon/dir/.py/homeworkBOT/main.py", line 43, in testform
    await form.start()
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/forms/form.py", line 221, in start
    embed.set_author(name=f"{self.title}: {n+1}/{len(self._questions)}", icon_url=self._bot.user.avatar_url)
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'
```

I don't understand what is meant by `'avatar_url'` because I don't use it in my code
I looked on the internet but apparently no one else had the problem with `discord.py`

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The code you provided is missing the part where you use avatar_url, but from the error it could be because of _bot instead of bot

Comment: That's the strange thing, I don't use avatar_url @Karo

Comment: you do somewhere in the embed you are using, check your error message and the answer i provided below, this should fix it :)

Comment: Ah, you are using discord-ext-forms, did you import everything correctly and is it a main file or a cog file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the module „forms“ from discord.ext, I can only guess that it is an error of the module itself, if you know how, open the file discord-ext-forms/discord/ext/forms
/form.py and search for „avatar_url“ and replace that part with "avatar" since avatar_url is now avatar

Comment: @Diego Reim it is because of ext/forms